# 1. is not a valid ruby floating number

Tags: ruby, literals, pry

1. I found that `1.` is not a valid float in Ruby. Am I correct?
2. Why did the prompt have a star symbol in the second line as shown below?

   ```
   [5] pry(main)> puts 1.
   [5] pry(main)*
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`period` in ruby is used for calling `methods` on that object not only `decimal points`.

Does that make `1` an `object`?

Yes! you can do

```
1.class
#=> Fixnum
```

Thus, it is an object of class `Fixnum`. There are multiple methods which can be called on `1`, one being

```
[5] pry(main)> put 1. #enter
[5] pry(main)* next
#=> 2
```

So that `*` means the syntax is incomplete and waiting for the `method` to be called on `1`.

To see the list of available methods, you can do

1.methods

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. :)

Comment: I am glad. Please accept the answer if it makes sense to you.. :)

Comment: Good answer. In Ruby v2.4+, `1.class #=> Integer`. OP: do you now see why Ruby requires a digit after the period for floats?

Comment: And for the alternative ways to input the floating number: `Float(1)`, `1.to_f`, `1e0` or just `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

period is not only for float. so 1. may be followed by several things, not decimals only

Comment: "several things"? "Integer instance methods" would be more informative.

Comment: Cary Swoveland yee sorry :(